# Creating spark pipeline without using tokenizer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I'm looking into creating a pipeline to run logistic regression in spark and I'm running into an issue on whether there is either a way I can extend or bypass the "Tokenizer" object.

Essentially, the problem I'm running into is that the tokenizer is not nearly precise enough for the vectors I'm trying to create (i.e. stemming, lemmatization, bi-grams etc.), but in EVERY example for spark pipelines I see something along the lines of:

```
val tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
  .setInputCol("text")
  .setOutputCol("words")
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
  .setNumFeatures(1000)
  .setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol)
  .setOutputCol("features")
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.001)
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(tokenizer, hashingTF, lr))
```

Must I have a tokenizer stage? Would it be trivial to extend the Tokenizer class to do the string modifications I want? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So I found a pretty decent example of extending the tokenizer class right here. This should give a pretty good roadmap of what needs to be overloaded for proper tokenization.

https://github.com/fyrz/spark-java-text-classifier/blob/master/src/main/java/org/fyrz/textclassifier/tokenizer/SparkLuceneTokenizer.java